# How to stop Roll Rotation in Mouse Look Script

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I am using FPS in Unity3D and I want only Pitch and Yaw. After some moves my Mouse Look Script start Rotating around z-axis (i.e. ROLL). How to stop that?

This is the Script that i am using for Mouse Look.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MouseLooking : MonoBehaviour
{

    float sensitivityX = 10f;
    float sensitivityY = 10f;
    public float minimumX = -360;
    public float maximumX = 360;
    public float minimumY = -60;
    public float maximumY = 60;
    public float delayMouse = 3;
    public float noiseX = 0.1f;
    public float noiseY = 0.1f;
    public bool Noise;

    private float rotationX = 0;
    private float rotationY = 0;
    private float rotationXtemp = 0;
    private float rotationYtemp = 0;
    private Quaternion originalRotation;
    private float noisedeltaX;
    private float noisedeltaY;
    private float stunY;
    private float breathHolderValtarget = 1;
    private float breathHolderVal = 1;
    private TouchScreenVal touch;


    void Start ()
    {
            if (rigidbody)
                    rigidbody.freezeRotation = true;
            originalRotation = transform.localRotation;

            sensitivityX = sensitivityY = 10;

            touch = new TouchScreenVal (new Rect (0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height));

    }



    void Update ()
    {
            sensitivityY = sensitivityX;
            //      Screen.lockCursor = true;

            stunY += (0 - stunY) / 20f;

            if (Noise) {
                    noisedeltaX += ((((Mathf.Cos (Time.time) * Random.Range (-10, 10) / 5f) * noiseX) - noisedeltaX) / 100);
                    noisedeltaY += ((((Mathf.Sin (Time.time) * Random.Range (-10, 10) / 5f) * noiseY) - noisedeltaY) / 100);
            } else {

                    noisedeltaX = 0;
                    noisedeltaY = 0;
            }
            #if UNITY_EDITOR
            rotationXtemp += (Input.GetAxis ("Mouse X") * sensitivityX) + (noisedeltaX * breathHolderVal);
            rotationYtemp += (Input.GetAxis ("Mouse Y") * sensitivityY) + (noisedeltaY * breathHolderVal);
            rotationX += (rotationXtemp - rotationX) / delayMouse;
            rotationY += (rotationYtemp - rotationY) / delayMouse;
            #else

    if (Constants.isGameOver == false) {

        int  count = Input.touchCount;


        if (Input.touchCount > 0) {

            for(int i =0 ; i< count ; i++)
            {



                Touch touch1 = Input.GetTouch (i);
                if ((touch1.phase == TouchPhase.Moved )  || touch1.phase == TouchPhase.Stationary) {

                    rotationX = rotationXtemp + ( Input.GetTouch (i).deltaPosition.x * sensitivityX* Time.deltaTime) + (noisedeltaX * breathHolderVal);
                    rotationY = rotationYtemp + ( Input.GetTouch(i).deltaPosition.y * sensitivityY* Time.deltaTime) + (noisedeltaY * breathHolderVal);

       //                       rotationX = rotationXtemp + (touch.OnDragDirection(true).x * sensitivityX * Time.deltaTime) + (noisedeltaX * breathHolderVal);
      //                        rotationY = rotationYtemp + (-touch.OnDragDirection(true).y * sensitivityY * Time.deltaTime) + (noisedeltaY * breathHolderVal);



                }
            }




        }
        else
        {

            rotationX = rotationXtemp + (touch.OnDragDirection(true).x * sensitivityX * Time.deltaTime) + (noisedeltaX * breathHolderVal);
            rotationY = rotationYtemp + (-touch.OnDragDirection(true).y * sensitivityY * Time.deltaTime) + (noisedeltaY * breathHolderVal);
        }


    }


            #endif

            if (rotationX >= 360) {
                    rotationX = 0;
                    rotationXtemp = 0;
            }
            if (rotationX <= -360) {
                    rotationX = 0;
                    rotationXtemp = 0;
            }

            rotationX = ClampAngle (rotationX, minimumX, maximumX);
            rotationY = ClampAngle (rotationY, minimumY, maximumY);
            rotationYtemp = ClampAngle (rotationYtemp, minimumY, maximumY);


            Quaternion xQuaternion = Quaternion.AngleAxis (rotationX, Vector3.up);
            Quaternion yQuaternion = Quaternion.AngleAxis (rotationY + stunY, Vector3.left);

            transform.localRotation = originalRotation * xQuaternion * yQuaternion;
            breathHolderVal += (breathHolderValtarget - breathHolderVal) / 10;  

            #if !UNITY_EDITOR
    rotationXtemp = rotationX;
    rotationYtemp = rotationY;
            #endif
    }

    public void Holdbreath (float val)
    {
            breathHolderValtarget = val;
    }

    public void Stun (float val)
    {
            stunY = val;
    }

    static float ClampAngle (float angle, float min, float max)
    {
            if (angle < -360.0f)
                    angle += 360.0f;

            if (angle > 360.0f)
                    angle -= 360.0f;

            return Mathf.Clamp (angle, min, max);
    }
}
```

Comment: There are quite a few ways to get this work and not work. Could you post your code so that I can see what you're doing currently?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use floats to store the x and y rotation, you need to store it all in a quaternion.  So when you update from the mouse input, add it directly to the quaternion.

See [Quaternion rotation without Euler angles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17044296/quaternion-rotation-without-euler-angles) for example.